# Are there any shortcuts for a quick save?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there any shortcut for a quick save in StarCraft II?

I remember that it always was in Blizzard's strategies but I can't find it in SC2.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of "Auto-Save"?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer, no I'm looking for something I can trigger manually  but without going to Menu -> Save...

Comment: You should consider changing your accepted answer

Comment: @Juan Manuel, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of Patch 1.1, Quicksave functionality has been added to starcraft 2.

Ctrl + Q will save the game.

Source: https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/starcraft2/842870/patch-1-1-0-now-live

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell from searching and checking the hotkey options there is not key for this, however a quick key combination to save game would be:

F10-S-Enter

That brings up Menu, selects Save, and Enter submits the save file with the default chosen name and returns you to the game.

It's pretty fast see: http://www.ryancalderoni.com/archive/quick_save.swf

Comment: I've checked hotkey option as well and was aware of `F10`, `S`, `Enter`... Just as quite regular action I thought it would make sense to have a dedicated shortcut for that...

Comment: I guess they decided it's not really needed, kind of like how Mac OS doesn't use 'Apply' buttons like Windows does, they just designed it in such a way that it's not really necessary though people might feel like they want it at first because they are used to it, ya know?

Comment: yeah, I guess, they've done similar with the traditional "Exit Program" menu item -- now you have to use standard Windows' `Alt+F4` shortcut.